# 2 Fact tables and business wants to know percent of total of one fact to another fact

Tags: reporting, data-warehouse

We have 2 Fact table in our warehouse.
CaseFacts and IncidentFacts.  Both have dimension joins to date dimension and other various items

In our OLTP these 2 tables are related as each Incident of a Case.  So a Case can have multiple Incidents.

OLTP table structure

- Cases Table CaseId (Primary key)
- Address
- etc..

Incident Table

- IncidentId (Primary)
- CaseId (Foreign key to Cases table)
- IncidentType
- etc..

Case is 1:n to Incidents

The question is this:
The business wants to know the Percent of total cases that have an IncidentType of "X"

In our warehouse, if we don't join one fact table to another, I'm not sure what the best way to handle this.

Basic data of what I need:

1. Need distinct CaseId and IncidentType for a date time range
2. Then need incident type counts (numerator)
3. then need number of Cases in that same time range (denominator)
4. then could be grouped by anything else like State, Region, Department..

Not sure what to do for the warehouse structure if needing 2 data points from different datamarts essentially.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard pattern in data warehousing: the correct approach (in most circumstances) is to retrieve the data in 2 separate queries, join the 2 result sets together (using the common, conformed, dimensions) and then query this combined result set to get the final answer.

For your specific example I would suggest:

**Query 1**: count distinct CaseId from incident table grouped by any required dimension values

**Query 2**: count IncidentId from incident table where IncidentType = "X" grouped by any required dimension values (may need additional logic if a case can have multiple incidents of the same type and how you want to handle this in your calculation). These grouping values would need to match those in Query 1.

**Query 3**: join Query 1 results to Query 2 results by the common "group by" fields and divide one count by the other to get the percentage

Exactly how you would write this in SQL would depend on your DBMS but using CTEs is probably the easiest solution in most cases

Comment: Thanks NickW.  I appreciate the quick feedback.  That's what I was thinking, but I questioned if there were alternatives I didn't think of.  Thanks